# Java installation disappearing on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, jre

I have installed jre version 1.8.0_51 on a 64-bit Windows 7. Some time after the installation I could not run java programs anymore, seemingly because the installation dissapeared. If I run "java -version" in the command line, then java is not recognized. If I reinstall the java it works for some time again, and after that it is not recognized anymore. So I always have to reinstall the java every time I want to run a program.

I don't know how to find out what's happening, but it is extremely annoying, any hint would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to remove all java from the computer, restart the system and then clean out the Java folders and delete all Java registry entries.

Be aware that playing around in the registry can lead to a complete failure of windows. Make a backup first!

Comment: What registry entries should be removed specifically?  What folders should be removed exactly?

Answer (score 0):

#### Some time after the installation I could not run java programs anymore

> seemingly because the installation disappeared.

1. Completely remove the JRE using [JavaRa](https://singularlabs.com/software/javara/) (JavaRa forcibly deletes files, directories and registry keys associated with the JRE).
2. Reinstall the JRE.

---

#### How do I completely remove an old installation of the JRE?

> JavaRa is an effective way to deploy, update and remove the Java
>   Runtime Environment (JRE). It can assist in repairing or removing Java
>   when other methods fail.
>
> [image]
>
> **Its most significant feature is the
>   JRE Removal tool; which forcibly deletes files, directories and
>   registry keys associated with the JRE.**

---

#### Disclaimer

I am not affiliated with [JavaRa](https://singularlabs.com/software/javara/) in any way, I am just an end user of the software.

Comment: It is worth pointing out that JavaRa has been discontinued since starting with the most recent updates of both Java 7 and Java 8, the Java installer, properly removes Java.  I have actually ran into a situation where JavaRa couldn't solve a problem with a more recent version of Java, which I was trying to uninstall to replace it with a more current version, for that reason.